# JQM, keyboard hide input form - phonegap android

Tags: jquery, cordova

I build with phonegap simple android app.
Using latest jquery mobile.

I have page with fixed header and footer.
On that page i have form with few input fields and text area.

When click on input field, it show android keyboard, but keyboard hide my input field, so i don't see what i writing in that field.

Do you know way how android keyboard don't hide input fields?

I know way to write in config.xml that fulscreen = false, but does exist another way?

Thanks

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying android manifest in the activity section. This will move the screen up above the keyboard.

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

More info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html